# Can I use jar file in maven m2 directory to manually install in Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven

I want to use the jar files in maven's m2 directory from Windows to install the same artifact and same version to Linux. There is maven available in Linux. And I want to install the package using the command :

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=xxx.filepath.jar -DgroupId=xxx.org.group.id -DartifactId=xxx.packageartifactid -Dversion=xxx.1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar.

Does that work?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: You got any error? Post your error here for better helping.

Answer (score 0):

jar files are intended to run on any OS on which a JVM exists unless you have OS-specific code in your files.